# Add a character in a string inside a column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with some numbers (or strings, it doesn't actually matter). The thing is that I  need to add a character in the middle of them. The dataframe looks like this (I got it from Google Takeout)

```
 id       A         B
  1    512343    -1234
  1    213       1231345
  1    18379     187623
```

And I want to add a comma in the second position

```
  id      A             B
   1    51,2343    -12,34
   1    21,3        12,31345
   1    18,379      18,7623
```

A and B are actually longitude and latitude so I think it is not possible to achieve to add the comma in the right place since there is no way to know if a number is supposed to have one or two digits as coordinates, but it would do the trick if I can put the comma on the second position.

Comment: Do you need commas? Why not keep them as floats since Latitude and Longitude are numeric?

Comment: @ALollz OP already mentioned that, and said second place would do for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
df[["A", "B"]]=df[["A", "B"]].astype(str).replace(r"(\d{2})(\d+)", r"\1,\2", regex=True)
```

Outputs:

```py
   id        A         B
0   1  51,2343    -12,34
1   1     21,3  12,31345
2   1   18,379   18,7623
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach with `str.extract`:

```
for c in ['A','B']:
    df[c] = df[c].astype(str).str.extract('(-?\d{2})(\d*)').agg(','.join,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   id        A         B
0   1  51,2343    -12,34
1   1     21,3  12,31345
2   1   18,379   18,7623
```

Comment: Sorry but for some reason your code doesn't work properly.. It gives the correct output when the number has an odd number of digits, but it appends a 0 when the number of digits is even.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this -

```
import numpy as np
df['A'] = np.where(df['A']>=0,'', '-') + ( df['A'].abs().astype(str).str[:2] + ',' + df['A'].abs().astype(str).str[2:] )
df['B'] = np.where(df['B']>=0,'', '-') + ( df['B'].abs().astype(str).str[:2] + ',' + df['B'].abs().astype(str).str[2:] )
df
   id        A         B
0   1  51,2343    -12,34
1   1     21,3  12,31345
2   1   18,379   18,7623
```